# Codeigniter load models in a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Two or more loaded controllers with the same name login models are not working.

E.g I have two models from same name one is `login_model` and other is in `admin -> login_model.php` then I want to load both in a single controller.

How can I do that?

Comment: are you using  autoload are loading in  page ?

Comment: Both will have same variable name `login_model` which means the one you called 2nd will be active.If you want to use both you need to use one of them as other variable.Look at [doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model) how you can give another object name for a model

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like this:

```
$this->load->model("login_model","login_model");

$this->load->model("admin/login_model","admin_login_model");
```

Comment: This is the only answer that is correct. By the way if you are going to rename things - you actually don't need the word "model" in the name.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$this->load->model('admin/login_model' , 'myinterest');
The second parameter (optional) is used to call the method.

 ex:

 $this->myinterest->get_users();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to place admin model in another folder, say in admin folder

so your code will be like below

```
 $this->load->model('login_model');
 $this->load->model('admin/login_model');
```

This will call both model in same controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well:

```
$this->load->model("admin/login_model","login_model");
```